# Knots realized as algebraic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, knot-theory, real-algebraic-geometry

Two questions:

> **Q1**. Have researchers worked out minimum-degree
> real algebraic curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$ realizing specific knots?

Some work on the trefoil is reported in [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/148916/237).

---

[image]

---

In particular,
[David Speyer's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3269310/237)
reached a pair of two-variable polynomial equations each of degree $6$,
whose intersection is the trefoil above.
But I don't know if this is the minimum degree
(which was not the point of the cited question).

> **Q2**. Are there known bounds relating the crossing number
> $\operatorname{cr}(K)$ of a knot $K$
> to the minimum degree of an algebraic curve realizing $K$?

Comment: To be clear, you're talking about real algebraic curves in real $3$-space, right? What notion of degree are you using?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn:1st, *Yes*, an algebraic curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Edited to make that explicit.. 2nd, I am content with any definition of degree. I haven't found min-degree results under any notion of "degree."

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: If the curve is represented as the intersection of two surfaces, then one might use the max of the degree of the surfaces. And the degree of a surface is the maximum number of intersections it has with any straight line.

Comment: I'd be careful with 'degree of a surface is the maximum number of intersections' — shapes like superellipses ($x^4+y^4+z^4=1$) that are convex are only going to have two intersections with any straight line. Isn't it easier just to say that the degree of a surface $S(x,y,z)=0$ is the polynomial degree of $S$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: You are right; I didn't think that through. Better to just use the polynomial degree. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: The degree of an algebraic curve in (complex) 3-space is the number of intersection points of the curve with a generic plane.

Comment: One reference : Brugallé, Koseleff, Pecker, [The lexicographic degree of the first two-bridge knots](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06393)